# Using an image as a background of a UIViewController and supporting multiple screen sizes

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage

On some view controllers I am using images as background for the whole screen. I was wondering what is the best practice for this, since I want to support all currently available iPhones (5-7). Normally for images I would get @2x and @3x image, but here the case is  a little bit different?

Do I add 4 photos to app and then ask system on which device i am running and than load appropriate photo? This seems kinda clunky, an not really elegant.

Comment: Use `xcassets` to do this, the system will take care of loading the required resolution automatically. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/AddingImages.html

Comment: Remember you still have to support iPhone 4S aspect ratio in case your app is run on the iPad. I use `@2x` for 4,5,6 and 7 scaling or cropping. (whatever looks best) and `@3x` for 6/7plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have that many options.

You could bundle different images for the different device aspect ratios, check the device aspect ratio at runtime, and load the correct image.  This implementation is flawed, as it doesn't account for future device aspect ratios.  You could have a webservice which returns a correct image for a given aspect ratio, to take that work off of the client.

You could also create a single image that looks good on all device sizes, and load the image into a `UIImageView` and set its `contentMode` `UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill` to fill the entire image into the view's frame, cropping some portion of the top, bottom, or sides out.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this in my projects by using the 'xcassets'. The system basically takes care of the 'which device size' question for you. Also, play around with the differing contentMode properties (i.e.'aspectFit', 'aspectFill', 'scaleToFill').

Another thing I would watch out for is the value for 'autoResizingMask' property. In most cases if my sizing isn't doing what I think it should, I check if I gave autoResizingMask a value of 'No'.

I hope this helps!